# how to set TCP connect timeout in scrapy?

Tags: scrapy

When crawling a slow website, I always get the error: TCP connection timed out: 10060. I guess this may happen when the crawler tries to establish a TCP connection with the server and the default connect timeout is too low.

I know the download timeout can be set in scrapy, but I found no way to set the connect timeout. Does anyone have some ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's the difference between _connection_ timeout and _download_ timeout?  With the aid of the `DownloadTimeoutMiddleware`, `scrapy.resolver.CachingThreadedResolver` calls Twisted's `ThreadedResolver.getHostByName` with the value of `settings.getint('DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT')`.

Comment: @StevenAlmeroth how to set 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT'

Answer (score 6):

DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT can be set in settings.py in your scrapy project

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-timeout